# ionic : Search bar on the navbar

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

i would like to add a search icon on the navbar of my ionic's project

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
<ion-title *ngIf="!searchBox">Destiny Pro 1.0</ion-title>

<ion-searchbar *ngIf="searchBox"></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-buttons right>
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="showSearchBox()">
        <ion-icon  *ngIf="!searchBox" md="md-options" ></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

[image]

But the ion-icon doesn't appear.

Comment: Can you simulate your issue here https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I am more an Angular dev but i prefer to use [class.hidden]="searchBox" it takes the opposite rule of ngIf but better render the changes. I had a similar issue with google map popups. So try it if it exists in Ionic & let me know...
I assume you are changing the value of searchBox in your showSearchBox() function ?

Comment: You mean `[style.hidden]="searchBox"`?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it & it's working.

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
<ion-title *ngIf="!searchBox">Destiny Pro 1.0</ion-title>

<ion-searchbar *ngIf="searchBox" ></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-buttons right>
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="showSearchBox()">
        <ion-icon  *ngIf="!searchBox" md="md-options" ></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Here's a [working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6ef1nk?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)